# How to Get and Set Selected Item from Spinner Using SharedPreferences

Tags: android, android-fragments

I want to store selected item from spinner and once that fragment is again launch , previous selected Item should be selected , I tried but not able to get it.

I need to store selected position onClick of button only.

This is code which I am using :

```
spinner_level = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_activity_level);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(rootView.getContext(), R.array.activity_level, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spinner_level.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner_level.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
spinner_level.getSelectedItemPosition();

spinner_level.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
    {
        ((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        selected = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView) {

    }
});
```

Comment: What you have tried for saving value in `SharedPreferences` ?

Comment: I have no idea about it , how to do for Spinner .

Comment: You need to set the value on every initialization of the spinner, e.g. in `onCreate` of your Fragment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had used     editor.putInt("VALUE", spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the selected value each time you initialize the spinner in the Framgent's `onCreateView` where this code already resides:

```
spinner_level = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.spinner_activity_level);
ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(rootView.getContext(), R.array.activity_level, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
spinner_level.setAdapter(adapter);
spinner_level.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
spinner_level.getSelectedItemPosition();
int indexOfPreviousSelection = sharedPreferences.getInt("selectionIndex", 0);
spinner_level.setSelection(indexOfPreviousSelection);
```

You need to get `indexOfPreviousSelection` from `SharedPreferences`, I presume you know how to do that. And also you need to set the new value each time it changes:

```
 @Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id)
{
    ((TextView) parentView.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    selected = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putInt("selectionIndex", position);
    editor.apply();
}
```

`SharedPreferences sharedPreferences` should be a field in your Framgent which you'll initialize in `onAttach` or where you deem appropriate:

```
@Override
protected void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

Comment: I am getting Null Pointer Exception 05-30 11:16:17.655: E/AndroidRuntime(1217): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor android.content.SharedPreferences$Editor.putInt(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference

Comment: I made a typo at `editor.putInt("selectionIndex", position);`, it was `putString`, now I edited it. At what line are you getting that exception? You need to initialize the `editor` like in my code sample.