# get position of item in Custom ArrayAdapter(Spinner)

Tags: java, android

I save user selection and want to show user selected item by auto selecting spinner item when user comes back to activity.

TypesCustomArrayAdapter

```
public class TypesCustomArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private final LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<TypesSpinnerItemObject> items;
    private final int mResource;

    public TypesCustomArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
                                     @NonNull List objects) {
        super(context, resource, 0, objects);

        mContext = context;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        mResource = resource;
        items = objects;
    }
    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int position, @Nullable View convertView,
                                @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        return createItemView(position, convertView, parent);
    }

    @Override
    public @NonNull View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        return createItemView(position, convertView, parent);
    }


    private View createItemView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        final View view = mInflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);

        TextView txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView txtId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.code);


        TypesSpinnerItemObject item = items.get(position);
        txtName.setText(item.Name);
        txtId.setText(item.Id);

        return view;
    }
```

How I fill the spinner

```
ArrayAdapter vaziatSokonatAdapter = TypesCustomArrayAdapter(VillageInputActivity.this, R.layout.item_types_spinner, response.body());`
```

saving user selection:

```
Object ss = mySpinner.getSelectedItem();
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(ss);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("ss", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("ss", json);
editor.apply();
```

how I try to change selected item of the spinner:

```
SharedPreferences sh = getSharedPreferences("ss", MODE_PRIVATE);

String ss= sh.getString("ss", "");
Gson gson = new Gson();
Object ss = gson.fromJson(ss, mySpinner.getSelectedItem().getClass());
  mySpinner.setSelection(vaziatSokonatAdapter.getPosition(ss));
```

but vaziatSokonatAdapter.getPosition(ss) returns -1

Comment: Issue is here :- String ss= sh.getString("ss", "");     => String ss= sh.getString("dd", "") But it's not a nice way of saving and getting data of a spinner.

Comment: @ChandraShekhar Kaushik sorry  that was a typo here. I fix it

Comment: you could try to just simply save the position itself -> `getSelectedItemPosition() `instead of creating whole json object. And then `setSelection()` for selecting the item at desired position

Comment: Take a look to this link.
[it shows how to store and retrieve selected spinner item every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37481951/how-to-get-and-set-selected-item-from-spinner-using-sharedpreferences)

Comment: @P.Juni this way I have to save two values for each spinner. position and it's actual value but thanks

Comment: why do you need to save value ? You just need to set selection by using saved position and the value will be there.

Comment: @P.Juni I need value to send it to webservice when user submits the form.